# Datepicker will not show on modal

Tags: datepicker, asp-classic, bootstrap-modal

I am working on ASP classic and modal. I have a page resided in the root folder called tmshiftot. Clicking tmshiftot show button, it will display called an ajax function and display a content from another page which reside in a subfolder. Clicking on another link at the page will pop up a modal form. The modal div and function are in the root folder page tmshiftot, whereas the modal form resides in a subfolder. All my js and css files also resides in subfolder.

However, the datepicker won't load. I don't know where to put the js and css of datepicker and I suspect there is some linking issue. Please help me, thank you very much.

I have included the errors when debugging. Your help is gladly appreciated.

[The file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0exnx.gif)

[Running debugger and the erros](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iyul6.gif)

The ROOT page tmshiftot.asp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- #include file="include/connection.asp" -->
<!-- #include file="include/proc.asp" -->
<!-- #include file="include/option.asp" -->
<!-- #include file="include/adovbs.inc" -->
<!-- #include file="include/validate.asp" -->

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>IQOR</title>
<!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- DataTables -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css">
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="font_awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!-- Ionicons -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css">
<!-- Theme style -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
<!-- AdminLTE Skins. Choose a skin from the css/skins
    folder instead of downloading all of them to reduce the load. -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css">
<!-- Jquery 1.12.0 UI CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/jQuery-ui/1.12.0/Css/jquery-ui.css"/>
<!-- Date Picker -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/datepicker/datepicker3.css" />

</head>
<%
    sMonth = Month(Date)
    sYear = Year(Date)
%>

<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
  <div class="wrapper">

    <!-- #include file="include/header.asp" -->
    <!-- Left side column. contains the logo and sidebar -->
    <!-- #include file="include/sidebar_tm.asp" -->

    <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
        <section class="content-header">
            <h1>Time Clock Entry </h1>
        </section>
        <!-- Main content -->
        <section class="content">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="box">
                        <!-- /.box-header -->
                        <div class="box-body ">
                            <form name="form1" class="form-horizontal" action="tmshiftot.asp" method="POST">
                               <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Employee ID : </label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <input class="form-control" id="txtID" name="txtID" value="<%=sID%>" maxlength="6">
                                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                                <a href="#" name="btnSearchID" id="btnSearchID" class="btn btn-default"
                                                    data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-userID">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                                                </a>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                                        <button type="submit" id="btnShow" name="btnShow" class="btn btn-default"
                                            onclick="showContent();return false;" style="width: 90px">
                                            Show</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Start From : </label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-1" style="width:100px">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <select name="selMonth" id="selMonth" class="form-control">
                                                <%For j = 1 to 12 %>                                                         
                                                    <option value="<%=j%>" <%if sMonth = j then%>Selected<%end if%>><%=MonthName(j,true)%></option>
                                                <%Next%>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <select name="selYear" id="selYear" class="form-control">
                                                <%For i = 1 to 30 
                                                    selyear = Cint(2016) + Cint(i)
                                                %>
                                                    <option value="<%=selyear%>" <%if sYear = selyear then%>Selected<%end if%>><%=selyear%></option>
                                                <%Next%>

                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                            <div id="searchresult">
                                <!-- CONTENT HERE -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.box-body -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.col -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
           <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="modal-userID" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        </div>
                            <div id="userID">
                                <!--- Content ---->
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal fade" id="modal-shiftotentry">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Shift Maintenance Entry</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div id="shiftotentry"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <!-- /.modal-content -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal -->
        </section>
        <!-- /.content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.content-wrapper -->

    <!-- #include file="include/footer.asp" -->
</div>
<!-- ./wrapper -->
<!-- JQuery 2.2.3 Compressed -->
<script src="plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 -->
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Jquery 1.12.0 UI -->
<script src="plugins/jQuery-ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!-- Jquery for autocomplete -->
<script src="plugins/jQueryAutoComplete/jquery.ui.autocomplete.scroll.min.js"></script>
<!-- SlimScroll -->
<script src="plugins/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<!-- FastClick -->
<script src="plugins/fastclick/fastclick.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script src="dist/js/app.min.js"></script>
<!-- datepicker -->
<script src="plugins/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    document.getElementById('txtID').focus();
    });

$(function () {
    $("#btnShow").click(function () {
        $("#searchresult").show();
    });
});

</script>

<script>
function getValue(svalue) 
    {
        document.getElementById("txtID").value = svalue;
        $('#modal-userID').modal('hide');
    }

    $('#modal-userID').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
        var modal = $(this)
        showDetails('page=1')
    })

function showDetails(str){
    var xhttp;

    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("userID").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        }
    };

    var search = document.getElementById("txtID");
    if (search != null && search != "") 
    {
        str = str + "&txtEMP_ID=" + search.value;
    }

    xhttp.open("GET", "ajax/ax_view_userID.asp?"+str, true);
    xhttp.send();

}
</script>

<script>
function showContent() {
    var xhttp;

    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("searchresult").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        }
    };

    str = "txtEMP_ID=" + document.getElementById("txtID").value;
    str = str + "&txtMonth=" + document.getElementById("selMonth").value 
    str = str + "&txtYear=" + document.getElementById("selYear").value 
    xhttp.open("GET", "ajax/ax_tmshiftot_info.asp?"+str, true);
    xhttp.send();
}
</script>


<script>
      $('#modal-shiftotentry').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
        var recipient = button.data('sdate')
        recipient = recipient + "," + button.data('emp_id')
        var modal = $(this)
        modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient)
        showDetails2(recipient)
    })

function showDetails2(str){
    var xhttp;

    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("shiftotentry").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        }
    };

    xhttp.open("GET", "ajax/ax_tmshiftot_entry.asp?txtstring="+str, true);
    xhttp.send();

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The CONTENT page in a subfolder called ajax

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<!-- #include file="../include/connection.asp" -->
<!-- #include file="../include/proc.asp" -->
<!-- #include file="../include/option.asp" -->
<!-- #include file="../include/adovbs.inc" -->
<!-- #include file="../include/validate.asp" -->

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">


</head>
<body>
<div class="col-sm-12" style="overflow:auto;padding:0px;margin:0px">

 <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">

    <thead>
        <%
            response.write "<tr>"
                response.write "<th>Month</th>"
                For i = 1 to 31
                    if i < 10 then
                        i = "0" & i
                    end if
                    response.write "<th>" & i & "</th>"
                next
           response.write "<tr>"     
        %>             
    </thead>
     <tbody>
        <%  
            sURL = "&page=" & PageNo & "&txtEMP_ID=" & sEMP_ID
            sEMP_ID = request("txtEMP_ID")
            sBegMonth = CInt(request("txtMonth"))
            sBegYear = CInt(request("txtYear"))
            sEndMonth = CInt(sBegMonth) + 12

            do while sBegMonth <=sEndMonth

                sMonth = sBegMonth
                sYear = sBegYear
                if sMonth > 12 then
                    sMonth = sBegMonth mod 12
                    sYear = sBegYear + 1
                end if                        

                response.write "<tr>"
                response.write "<td>" & MonthName(sMonth,True) & "</td>"

                    For j = 1 to 31

                        sDate = j & "/" & sMonth & "/" & sYear

                        if IsDate(sDate) then 'Check if the date is valid
                            if weekday(sDate, 1) = 1 then 'Check if it is Sunday
                               response.write "<td bgcolor='#F08080'><a href='#' style='display:block;' data-toggle=""modal"" data-target=""#modal-shiftotentry"" data-emp_id=" & sYear & " data-sdate=" & sDate & ">&nbsp;</a></td>"
                            else
                               response.write "<td><a href='#' style='display:block;' data-toggle=""modal"" data-target=""#modal-shiftotentry"" data-emp_id=" & sYear & " data-sdate=" & sDate & ">&nbsp;</a></td>"
                            end if
                        end if    
                     next
                    response.write "</tr>"

            sBegMonth = sBegMonth + 1 

            loop
        %>                     
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The MODAL CODE page also in subfolder ajax

```
<!-- #include file="../include/connection.asp" -->
<!-- #include file="../include/adovbs.inc"-->
<!-- #include file="../include/proc.asp"-->

<% 
sMode = request("Mode")
sString = request("txtstring")
    if sString <> "" then
        sSplit = split(sString,",")
        sDate = sSplit(0)
        sEMP_ID = sSplit(1)
    end if

sModeSub = reqform("sub")
sShift_Code = reqform("txtShift_Code")
sID = UCase(reqform("txtEMP_ID"))
dt_Date = fdate2(reqform("txtdt_date"))

if sModeSub = "up" then
    sSQL = "UPDATE TMSHIFTOT SET "             
    sSQL = sSQL & " SHIFT_CODE = '" & sShift_Code & "',"
    sSQL = sSQL & " WHERE DT_SHIFT = '" & dt_Date & "'"
    sSQL = sSQL & " AND EMP_ID = '" & sID & "'"
    conn.execute sSQL

    call confirmBox("Update Successful!", "tmshiftot.asp")

elseif sModeSub = "save" then
    sSQL = "insert into TMSHIFTOT (EMP_ID,DT_SHIFT,SHIFT_CODE,USER_ID,DATETIME) "
    sSQL = sSQL & "values ("
    sSQL = sSQL & "'" & sID & "',"      
    sSQL = sSQL & "'" & dt_date & "',"
    sSQL = sSQL & "'" & sShift_Code & "',"
    sSQL = sSQL & "'" & session("USERNAME") & "'," 
    sSQL = sSQL & "'" & fdatetime2(Now()) & "'"
    sSQL = sSQL & ") "
    conn.execute sSQL
end if

Set rstTMSHIFTOT = server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")    
sSQL = "select * from TMSHIFTOT where DT_SHIFT ='" & fdate2(sDate) & "'" 
rstTMSHIFTOT.Open sSQL, conn, 3, 3
    if not rstTMSHIFTOT.eof then
        sShift_Code = rstTMSHIFTOT("SHIFT_CODE")
    end if
pCloseTables(rstTMSHIFTOT)

%>
<form class="form-horizontal" action="ax_tmshiftot_entry.asp" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="txtEMP_ID" value='<%=sEMP_ID%>' />
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Employee ID : </label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <span class="mod-form-control"><% response.write sEMP_ID %></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Shift Code : </label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input class="form-control" name="txtShift_Code" value="<%=sShift_Code%>" maxlength="30">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Dates From : </label>
                <div class="col-sm-8 col-lg-8">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input id="dt_From" name="dt_From" value="<%=sDate%>" type="text" class="form-control">
                        <div class="input-group-addon" style="background-color: gainsboro">
                            <span><b>To</b></span>
                        </div>
                        <input id="dt_To" name="dt_To" value="<%=dt_To%>" type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <%if sMode = "N" then %>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="submit" name="sub" value="up" class="btn btn-info pull-left" style="width: 90px">Update</button>
        <%else %>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="submit" name="sub" value="save" class="btn btn-primary-left" style="width: 90px">Save</button>
        <%end if %>
    </div>
 </div>
</form>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/datepicker/datepicker3.css" />
<!-- JQuery 2.2.3 Compressed -->
<script src="plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 -->
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- datepicker -->
<script src="plugins/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<script>
$(function () {
    //Date picker
    $("#dt_From").datepicker({
    autoclose: true, format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
    }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically adding the following part in the Showcontent()

```
    function showContent() {
    var xhttp;

    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("content2").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        $("[data-mask]").inputmask();
        $("[date-picker]").datepicker({
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
        autoclose: true,
        }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());


        }
    };

    xhttp.open("GET", "ax_test.asp?", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

All of your paths for included files in your `tmshiftot.asp` file seem to be based on the root folder.

But in the MODAL CODE, you reference the parent path (`../`) for included files.

I am guessing that the MODAL CODE is in a sub-folder, but keep in mind that if it is INCLUDEd from a script in the root folder, relative references in HTML will be based on the original scripts URL, not the sub-folder of the included script.

Try changing the following lines...

```
<link href="../plugins/datepicker/datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- JQuery 2.2.3 Compressed -->
<script src="../plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="../plugins/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
```

...to...

```
<link href="plugins/datepicker/datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- JQuery 2.2.3 Compressed -->
<script src="plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
```

(assuming that the plugins folder is at the root)

A better practice is to use absolute references. This means that references would be relative to the root folder. Absolute references start with a `/`.

You can do this with both asp includes by using virtual instead of file:

```
<!-- #include virtual="/include/yourfile.asp" -->
```

And any references within HTML (eg. script, link, a, img, etc):

```
<script src="/folder/filejs"></script>
```

If this isn't the answer, post any errors from the web developer tools console.

Comment: Hi Johna, thank you very much for helping me out here. I have followed your suggestions and changed all the css and js links. But the modal still won't load. I have edited my original post and included the code and video to show my folder structures and also the errors during debugging. Your help is gladly appreciated.

Comment: Try adding `/` or `/iqor/` to the beginning of each of the paths for each `script` and `link` include and see if that helps.